# Moving approval process to Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, approval-process

I have several approval processes that have been working in Classic for a long time and we are moving to Lightning Experience. What, if any, are approval process features that will no longer work in Lightning Experience or UI changes to the approval process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any approval process that is working in Classic will also work in Lightning. The only thing you have to take care is :-

You need to add the submit for approval button to lightning too by adding it on page layout in Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section. You need to select the action from Mobile and Lightning Action.

[image]

To debug any approval process:- [Approval Process not triggered successfully](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339897&type=1&mode=1)